# Sum of a column till certain count

Tags: bash, shell, unix, scripting

I have a file ABC.txt which contain two columns. First column refer to the count and second column refer to the subscriber as below :-

```
   1852 919474214491  
   1558 919475591746  
   1149 919475594574  
      1 919466423350
```

I have a variable in a script which shows some numeric value i.e Count is 3500.

So I want to compare the variable with first column in ABC.txt file. If value in first column is less than variable than move the value in second column in a separate file (123.txt). Go to next row, now add 1852 with 1558 and compare again with variable, if it is less than variable then move value in second column in file 123.txt. But if the sum of count is more than variable then stop.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Noted on the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really easy to do with awk:

```
$ awk -v count=3500 '{ total += $1 } total >= count { exit } { print $2 }' ABC.txt
919474214491
919475591746
```